# Unable to access member from inherited java class outside in kotlin

Tags: java, inheritance, kotlin

I am very new to Kotlin, I was trying to migrate my java project to kotlin and I ran into a problem where I can't access implicit inherited members from my class.

In java I had a class called `Robot.java` which extends from `TimedRobot.java` and inside the `TimedRobot.java` there is a static member which is a double type

```
public class Robot extends TimedRobot {
}
```

`TimedRobot.java` from the library:

```
public class TimedRobot extends IterativeRobotBase {
    public static final double DEFAULT_PERIOD = 0.02;
    private double m_period = DEFAULT_PERIOD;
    ...
}
```

In the same package as the `Robot.java` I have a class called `RobotConstants.java` which holds some numbers. Even though there was no variable called `DEFAULT_PERIOD` in my Robot class I was still able to call it from outside like this:

```
public class RobotConstants {
    public static final int PERIOD_IN_MS = (int)(Robot.DEFAULT_PERIOD * 1000);
    ...
}
```

However I am not able to do that in kotlin.

My robot class in kotlin:

```
class Robot : TimedRobot() {
}
```

And I am unable to get the default period in my constants object in kotlin, it gives me a compile time error. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
object RobotConstants {
    const val PERIOD_Ms = (Robot.DEFAULT_PERIOD * 1000).toInt()
    ...
}
```

Comment: The static constants defined on a super type won't be accessible on the sub type in Kotlin (as opposed to Java). In your case, you could access `DEFAULT_PERIOD` only via `TimedRobot`

Comment: @s1m0nw1 thats a bummer to hear, but thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the actual `TimedRobot.DEFAULT_PERIOD` constant or redefine it via a companion object:

```
class Robot : TimedRobot() {
    companion object {
        const val DEFAULT_PERIOD = TimedRobot.DEFAULT_PERIOD
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to represent these values as top level fields.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still bugs anyone like I did, the solution is putting the @JvmField annotation on the field